# How to find the id of dragged control

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I am implementing drag and drop functionality among lables. I want to find the ID of a dragged control like label, button, etc so that I can assign a text to it.

I am not sure how to get that data through the events. Any suggestion will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Drag_Enter and DragOVer Events, to achieve the goal  [DragEnter Doucmentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter.aspx)
and [DragOver Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragover.aspx)

alternativily you can check following tutorials

- [Code project :  Drag and Drop in Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3598/Drag-and-Drop-files-from-Windows-Explorer-to-Windo)
- [Code Project : Drag and Drop UI in WinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20483/Drag-and-Drop-Windows-Form-Controls-Design-UI-at-R)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've done your research to figure out how to do drag and drop of controls on your form (and your question is really only limited to your question title: *How to find the id of dragged control*) most standard WinForm events provide a parameter (*`object sender`*) which represents the control used to invoke the event. You should be able to get its ID as you would normally.

Apparently it is less obvious how to consistently get the ID from a WinForm control. Luckily, Brian McMaster has a (fairly old *meaning only possibly relevant*)  [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianmcm/archive/2006/01/17/getting-the-winforms-id-of-a-control.aspx) for doing just that. In .NET 3.5 I'd probably use this old post as the start to an extension method for control objects.

If your question is broader than that then you may benefit from @Ravi's links, but on SO we generally expect that you do your own research. Please be sure to do so before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

check out **System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs** e

```
void MyControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var controlBeingDrag = (Label)sender; // cast from object
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
}
```

the control sending drag event is **object sender**